# Projection operator and closed subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

A projection operator on a Hilbert space $H$ is defined as operator that projects a vector $x$ of $H$ onto an closed subspace $S$ of $H$. Why the subspace $S$ has to be closed?

Comment: It depends: exactly what properties would you like your projection operator to have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S = \{x: P(x) = x\}$, so if the projection $P$ is continuous $S$ must be closed.

Comment: Can we say that if $S$ wasn't closed, the projection $P$ would be discontinuous function at some $x$'s so we couldn't project this $x$'s onto $S$?

Comment: We might project it onto $S$, but not with a continuous projection.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of projection could be regarded redundant. However something interesting is given by the case when your subspace is not closed, but a non-closed dense subset. To which vector do project your $x \notin S$ then?

Comment: Can you give an example of such an $S$?